# Difference between servlet.imageserver and servlet.filedownload

Tags: images, document

I have my images stored as documents.   I am able to access them by both these urls

1. `servlet/servlet.imageserver?id=<record id>&oid=<orgid>`
2. `servlet/servlet.filedownload?file=<recordid>`

I am able to access the same image by both the above mentioned urls. So, would like to understand the difference between them. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first URL allows us only to view the image in browser window while the **download** ,downloads the file from your browser to download location .

Comment: Thanks. Is that the only difference?

Comment: I guess so,Atleast i am aware of only this difference